# How does AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS work - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

so I have a code that sets up an alarm at a specified time. I'd like to specify the day of the week aswell. So far all examples I have found are using the Calendar class, however, I use AlarmClock. This is my code:

```
Intent openNewAlarm = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
        openNewAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, Integer.parseInt(time[0]));
        openNewAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, Integer.parseInt(time[1]));
        openNewAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, String.valueOf(reminder.getText()));
        openNewAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS, Calendar.SATURDAY);
        startActivity(openNewAlarm);
```

Notice the EXTRA_DAYS line. According to the description:

```js
/**
 * Bundle extra: Weekdays for repeating alarm.
 * <p>
 * Used by {@link #ACTION_SET_ALARM}.
 * </p><p>
 * The value is an {@code ArrayList<Integer>}. Each item can be:
 * </p>
 * <ul>
 * <li> {@link java.util.Calendar#SUNDAY},
 * <li> {@link java.util.Calendar#MONDAY},
 * <li> {@link java.util.Calendar#TUESDAY},
 * <li> {@link java.util.Calendar#WEDNESDAY},
 * <li> {@link java.util.Calendar#THURSDAY},
 * <li> {@link java.util.Calendar#FRIDAY},
 * <li> {@link java.util.Calendar#SATURDAY}
 * </ul>
 */
public static final String EXTRA_DAYS = "android.intent.extra.alarm.DAYS";
```

Documentation doesn't help me much or I'm unable to understand it:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#EXTRA_DAYS

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#SUNDAY

If not mistaken, by selecting Calendar.Sunday, when setting up the alarm, sunday should be ticked in the comboBox meaning that this alarm will repeat every sunday, but it doesn't.

How do I manage to select which days of the week should my alarm repeat?

Any help is welcomed and thanks for your time in advance.

EDIT: I'm using the

```js
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

on my manifest. The alarm works fine, just need to learn how to set the days of the week.

Comment: but you are using the permissions `com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM`?

Comment: yes, forgot to mention it. will edit now. thanks anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
The value is an {@code ArrayList<Integer>}.
```

You need to construct an `ArrayList<Integer>` from `Calendar.SATURDAY` and pass it to `putExtra()`

```
ArrayList<Integer> alarmDays= new ArrayList<Integer>();
alarmDays.add(Calendar.SATURDAY);
openNewAlarm.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS, alarmDays);
```

Comment: jesus, I'm so short sighted :/ Thanks for your help, been stuck with this for a couple days. Many thanks :D

Comment: It's very easy to miss such simple details in elaborate scheme of things. Happy to help. :)

Comment: It's very strange that it's explicitly an `ArrayList<>` and not a `List<>`