# Is it possible to set a specific date with the Alarm Clock?

Tags: android, setalarmclock

this is how I set my alarm clock:

```
//all this inside a onClickListener
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 8);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2020);

Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, Integer.parseInt(str1));
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, Integer.parseInt(str2));
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, title.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
startActivity(intent);
```

All this set very well the app alarm clock on my device regarding the time, but not for the date.

Example:

1. Current time: 12:00 Monday

   Time from my code: 13:00 Saturday

   The alarm clock sets to play (the ringtone) in 1 hour
2. Current time: 12:00 Monday

   Time from my code: 11:00 Tuesday

   The alarm clock sets to play (the ringtone) in 25 hours

I dont know how to use in particular this line of code:

`intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));`

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. You're supposed to pass an ArrayList of the `Calendar` constants for days of the week to set the alarm on. You can't set a specific date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does AlarmClock.EXTRA\_DAYS work - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391350/how-does-alarmclock-extra-days-work-android-studio)

Comment: @Nicolas no unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the an alarm for a specific date with an `AlarmClock` provider.

`AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS` is for repeating alarms. You could use something like `Calendar.SUNDAY` and it would ring every Sunday.

If you want more control over an alarm, you have to program it yourself. Look into the `AlarmManager` class. It allows you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future.